# How to hide the display of formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, keyboard-shortcuts

How to hide the display of formula in a protected range of Google sheet? In Excel, I can do that, but in Google sheet not finding any function. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide display of formula in protected range"?

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut key for hiding/unhiding of the formula is:

[image: 0]

---

The formula for showing formula is:

```
FORMULATEXT(A5)
```

[image: 0]

---

If you want to hide actual formulas in sheet from other people, create a new spreadsheet and use **`IMPORTRANGE`**

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID_OR_URL_OF_ORIGINAL_SPREADSHEET", "Sheet1!A:Z")
```

Comment: Suppose in cell A5 , formula is Sum (1+1) and in formula bar it will display the formula accordingly. Suppose I do not want to show the formula in my shared Google sheet. How will I do it? Is there any function available in Google sheet?

Comment: @Prodip I see, yes it is. use IMPORTRANGE fx. answer updated

Comment: I have already tried IMPORTRANGE, but the problem is it is unable to refresh google finance data on live market. Is there any other alternative way to overcome this issue?

Comment: you could perhaps publish the sheet and have it live (but avoid HTML coz that would be same as IMPORTRANGE feedback-vise). other than that, there are no more options you could exploit

Comment: Thanks for your information.

Comment: @Prodip https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers